# Negative dimension size on MaxPool

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've implemented the following model with Keras. Underneath, I am using Tensorflow.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=(3, 150, 150), padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last"))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

However, I get this exception:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,75,32].
```

I am using `SAME` padding, and a convolution of `2*2`, so the output should be `2*2` and I should be able to run MaxPooling on it.

I just can't understand how the input can get to the shape `[?,1,75,32]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the input size of your first convolution.

You're using tensorflow and the "channels-last" layout.
Therefore, you need to specify the x and y resolution before the channels.

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=(150, 150, 3), padding='SAME'))
```

Your initial shape is `[?, 3, 150, 150]`, pooling applies to the second and third item, that's how the shape `[?, 1, 75, 32]` was created.
The `32` is the number of filters in your convolution.

If you want to keep your filters along the first axis, Keras has a configuration file, under Linux this should be in /home/user/.keras/keras.json. In this configuration file you can change the channel layout, the option is called `image_data_format`. There you can switch between `channels_first` and `channels_last`.

Comment: I changed `channels_last` to `channels_first` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Where did you change it? In the config file? Did you remove the argument from the maxpooling?

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten to change the argument from MaxPool.